# Set the Values of Multiple Inputs When Selecting an Option using jQuery-UI Autocomplete

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, autocomplete, jquery-ui-autocomplete

Hello everyone I am newbie in java-script. So I hope that you can help me. When user set data into city field, i want to set data in country field automatically.
I have an xml file:

```
<ROWSET>
<ROW>
<city></city>
<country></country>
</ROW>
</ROWSET>
```

In html document I have two input fields

```
<input id="id_city">
<input id="country">
```

Here is my js code:

```
$.ajax({
    url: "/media/xml/country.xml", //your url
    type: "GET", //may not need this-fiddle did-default is GET
    dataType: "xml",
    success: function(xmlResponse) {
        var data = $("ROW", xmlResponse).map(function() {
            return {
                value: $("city", this).text() + ", " + ($.trim($("country", this).text()) || "(unknown country)")
            };
        }).get();
        $("#id_city").autocomplete({
            source: function(req, response) {
                var re = $.ui.autocomplete.escapeRegex(req.term);
                var matcher = new RegExp("^" + re, "i");
                response($.grep(data, function(item) {
                    return matcher.test(item.value);
                }));
            },
            minLength: 2,
            select: function(event, ui) {
                $("p#result").html(ui.item ? "Selected: " + ui.item.value + ", cityId: " + ui.item.id : "Nothing selected, input was " + this.value);
            }
        });
    }
});
```

I don't know how to set automatically data to country field 
Thanks.

Comment: And what's the question?

Comment: Sorry, I don't know how to set automatically data to country field

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok this should do it for you.  I've change the definition of `data` so it now has three properties:

- `label` which is the same as your original `value`.
- `city` so you can put it into your `#city` input.
- `country` so you can put it into your `#country` input.

This means you can use `ui.item.city` and `ui.item.country` in the select property of the autocomplete.

Because there are now have three properties you need to customise the autocomplete and tell it to use `label` for it's options which is what the [`_renderItem`](http://api.jqueryui.com/autocomplete/#method-_renderItem) section does.

```
$.ajax({
    url: "/media/xml/country.xml",
    type: "GET",
    dataType: "xml",
    success: function (xmlResponse) {
        var data = $("ROW", xmlResponse).map(function () {
            return {
                label: $("city", this).text() + ", " + ($.trim($("country", this).text()) || "(unknown country)"),
                city: $.trim($("city", this).text()),
                country: $.trim($("country", this).text())
            };
        }).get();
        $("#id_city").autocomplete({
            source: function (req, response) {
                var re = $.ui.autocomplete.escapeRegex(req.term);
                var matcher = new RegExp("^" + re, "i");
                response($.grep(data, function (item) {
                    return matcher.test(item.city);
                }));
            },
            minLength: 2,
            select: function (event, ui) {
                $("p#result").html(ui.item ? "Selected: " + ui.item.label + ", cityId: " + ui.item.city : "Nothing selected, input was " + this.value);
                $("#id_city").val(ui.item.city);
                $("#country").val(ui.item.country);
                return false;
            },
            _renderItem: function (ul, item) {
                return $("<li></li>")
                    .data("value", item)
                    .append("<a>" + item.label + "</a>")
                    .appendTo(ul);
            }
        });
    }
});
```

Also I've created a "working" [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/a2sv97c9/) (because your code is using an ajax XML source I've hardcoded the response in a variable and generated the autocomplete in the `error` property as the ajax request will always fail from jsfiddle.net).

Comment: Thank you for your answer. But there an error TypeError: $(...).autocomplete(...).data(...) is undefined
 }).data("autocomplete")._renderItem = function(ul, item) {

Comment: @ZagorodniyOlexiy Ah yes, sorry about that.  It looks like they have changed jQuery-UI since I used the original code pattern in my project.  I've updated it now.